# FFmpeg realtime audio editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, ffmpeg, html5-audio

So I use FFmpeg to manipulate my audio files but there is no way of knowing what it will sound like before I actually upload the file(HTML form).

Is there a way to edit the audio with a real-time player or something?

I cannot find anything about this, thats why I am asking this question.

`$cmd = 'ffmpeg.exe -i path/to/audio.mp3 -filter:a asetrate=54000,atempo=' . $speed . ' output.mp3 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output);`

So can I replace `atempo=$speed` with real-time input? And listen to it on my website before I actually process it.

Not sure if it is even possible with FFmpeg.

Comment: Why can’t you just play `output.mp3` on your local computer before uploading it?

Comment: @MTCoster Because `output.mp3` does not exist yet. It's only created after FFmpeg is executed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything that can make this work.

Comment: Why do you not have access to the output after running ffmpeg?

Comment: @MTCoster  I do have access after running it, but then the changes have been processed. I need to know what the changes will sound like before I process them.

Comment: So you want to hear what the output will sound like *before* running ffmpeg?

Comment: @MTCoster exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real time editor does not seem possible with FFmpeg. You can stream real time, but you cannot output actual edits into your website.